# everytime i use apt update .. here is what is says , i have even tried sudo apt-get update but the problem remains the same

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

```
**Reading package lists... Done
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
**
```

Comment: You would not see those errors with `sudo`.  Please try it again.  Sometimes, `apt` can't get the lock file if there is another `apt` running.  You might do `ps axf | grep apt` to check that.

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
 have tried sudo .. this is what it says while using it as a super user ....

Comment: axf command not found....

Comment: (1) Then `apt` is already running, perhaps doing automatic daily updates for you.  (2) Then you didn't type the command correctly.  `ps` is available on every Unix system.

Comment: error can means that `apt` is running or it was stoped in wrong way and it couldn't remove `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` at the end - and you may have to remove it manually. You should also check other files and folders - `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial`, `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin`, `/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin` because they may have wrong  privileges and they may need manuall correction.

Comment: error `axf command not found....` can mean you wrote `axf` but you should use `ps axf`. OR you don't use standard unix program `ps` but maybe `powershell` which runs `axf` as command in `powershell`